# Trying to use CoreSpotlight on OSX

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xcode9, corespotlight

I'm trying to add spotlight integration to my mac app but get error. Here're the steps:

- I've created a new cocoa app
- I've added CoreSpotlight and CoreServices frameworks to the "Link binary with libraries" section of my project build settings and picked them as optional
- Added import CoreSpotlight to the head of my view controller
- import CoreServices to the head of my view controller

Then I've added the line to the viewDidLoad of my viewController

```
let _ = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeText as String)
```

Then I run the app, the project crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

[image]

I've already cleaned the project, deleted derived data, restarted my mac, etc...

I'm running on XCode Version 9.0 (9A235) and MacOX Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29).

Any suggestions may help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the same happens when you use it instead of setting to '_' ?

Comment: Yes. I get the same error also when I assign it to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CoreSpotlight documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight/cssearchableitemattributeset) suggests that API was added on macOS in High Sierra (10.13).

> SDKs
>
> iOS 9.0+
>
> macOS 10.13+

I can confirm it works for me on macOS 10.13.

Since you are running 10.12, the API does not exist.

Comment: Did you test it in 10.13 beta version of OSX?

Comment: @emreoktem release version

Comment: I think Core Spotlight is broken on  macOS 10.13 -  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83069
Does it still work for you ?